# How send a single email from an azure app service webapp

Tags: azure, smtp, azure-web-app-service

I want to send an automatic email from an Azure App Service (ASP.Net C# application).

Is there an SMTP server provided by azure ?

Thanks

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/

Comment: Nope, but you can use external services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email

Answer (score 4):

If you need to send a custom email from your code, you'll need to use a third party authenticated relay service like SendGrid. Outbound SMTP is restricted in Azure.

There are also other approaches that leverage Azure Logic Apps for example to use built-in connectors that send from Outlook or Gmail. Search will reveal tutorials.

If "automatic email" relates to something happening with your app, you might be able to use a triggered [alert rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-overview#manage-alert-rules) based on Azure activity logs. For example, sending an email every time your app restarts.

Comment: Voice of experience, Sendgrid are terribly, awfully bad. Bad service, bad support, bad deliverability, and we often found their IP ranges blacklisted. Try something better like Postmark.

Comment: That's not my experience. SendGrid has been great. I don't know about support, but the functionality has been solid.

Comment: Do you think i can create an office365 mailbox ? I just have to send few emails, this is not for marketing purposes

Comment: Yes, sending from an Office 365 account is fine as long as you stay under the send limits, which I believe is 30 messages per minute or something.