# Send registration emails from Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, azure, sendmail

I have a MEAN Stack application hosted in Azure which targets users from different organizations. The Node API app is hosted as an App Service. When a user registers, I have to send a verification email to their email-id from a common email-id (like *hello@contoso.com*). I have an Office 365 Business custom email account for this purpose.
I googled a lot about this but most of the Microsoft documents are talking about using logged in user's credential to access Graph API ("me/sendMail"). I want to implement the email feature independent of logged in user. Please suggest a good design. Sample code will help me save time.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I wrote an app which uses a logged-in users credentials (using msalClient). This works but it requires the user to login. another drawback was that the email always reaches the junk folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***We can Use an authenticated SMTP relay service, which is known as a Smart Host, with TLS capability to deliver emails from Azure VMs or App services.***

The most common SMTP relay service to integrate with Microsoft Azure is ***SendGrid***.

For complete setup and more information please refer to this [***BLOG***](https://mailtrap.io/blog/azure-send-email/) &  [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68484805/how-send-a-single-email-from-an-azure-app-service-webapp)

Comment: I was looking for some GraphAPI interface. But looks like I dont have anything other than sendgrid. Thanks.